# How to connect/disconnect a network not found by netsh?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, netsh

I use a network which can be found with `ipconfig` but cannot with `netsh wlan show networks` or `netsh wlan show interfaces`. I assume this may not be a `wlan` network but something else. I know it's cellular broadband connection but don't know where's on the list while typing `netsh ?`.

How can I found it out?

Maybe `netsh` is not the right to manage the network? Could I use something else?

**EDIT**

I must say the internet device is an Xuawei usb modem and I also tried to redial it using `rasdial` but this command says "no connections".

This is my `ipconfig /all` output (I don't know how to switch to english):

```
C:\Users\cp>ipconfig /all

Konfiguracja IP systemu Windows

   Nazwa hosta . . . . . . . . . . . : Manifold-4
   Sufiks podstawowej domeny DNS . . :
   Typ węzła . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrydowy
   Routing IP włączony . . . . . . . : Nie
   Serwer WINS Proxy włączony. . . . : Nie

Karta Ethernet Połączenie sieciowe Bluetooth 4:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Urządzenie Bluetooth (sieć osobista) #4
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : CC-52-AF-03-93-DA
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Tak
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta komórkowego połączenia szerokopasmowego Komórkowe połączenie szerokopasmowe 4:

   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : HUAWEI Mobile Connect - Network Adapter #4
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 0C-5B-8F-27-9A-64
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak
   Adres IPv6 połączenia lokalnego . : fe80::dd42:8394:b71f:f47c%44(Preferowane)
   Adres IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.143.207.97(Preferowane)
   Maska podsieci. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Brama domyślna. . . . . . . . . . : 10.143.207.98
   Identyfikator IAID DHCPv6 . . . . : 940333967
   Identyfikator DUID klienta DHCPv6 : 00-01-00-01-1B-FE-51-C7-B4-99-BA-F5-05-C5
   Serwery DNS . . . . . . . . . . . : 194.204.159.1
                                       194.204.152.34
   NetBIOS przez Tcpip . . . . . . . : Włączony

Karta bezprzewodowej sieci LAN Połączenie sieci bezprzewodowej 6:

   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 18-3D-A2-25-21-B9
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Tak
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak
   Adres IPv6 połączenia lokalnego . : fe80::495d:a769:39bd:d5f3%21(Preferowane)
   Adres IPv4 autokonfiguracji . . . . : 169.254.213.243(Preferowane)
   Maska podsieci. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Brama domyślna. . . . . . . . . . :
   Identyfikator IAID DHCPv6 . . . . : 639122850
   Identyfikator DUID klienta DHCPv6 : 00-01-00-01-1B-FE-51-C7-B4-99-BA-F5-05-C5
   Serwery DNS . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS przez Tcpip . . . . . . . : Włączony

Karta bezprzewodowej sieci LAN Połączenie sieci bezprzewodowej 4:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN #4
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 18-3D-A2-25-21-B8
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta Ethernet Połączenie lokalne:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : B4-99-BA-F5-05-C5
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak
   Adres IPv6 połączenia lokalnego . : fe80::a8fc:8832:37dc:f7b2%29(Preferowane)
   Adres IPv4 autokonfiguracji . . . . : 169.254.247.178(Preferowane)
   Maska podsieci. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Brama domyślna. . . . . . . . . . :
   Identyfikator IAID DHCPv6 . . . . : 553668694
   Identyfikator DUID klienta DHCPv6 : 00-01-00-01-1B-FE-51-C7-B4-99-BA-F5-05-C5
   Serwery DNS . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS przez Tcpip . . . . . . . : Włączony

Karta Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak
   Adres IPv6 połączenia lokalnego . : fe80::3876:ae85:1177:7fd6%30(Preferowane)
   Adres IPv4 autokonfiguracji . . . . : 169.254.127.214(Preferowane)
   Maska podsieci. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Brama domyślna. . . . . . . . . . :
   Identyfikator IAID DHCPv6 . . . . : 587223126
   Identyfikator DUID klienta DHCPv6 : 00-01-00-01-1B-FE-51-C7-B4-99-BA-F5-05-C5
   Serwery DNS . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS przez Tcpip . . . . . . . : Włączony

Karta tunelowa isatap.{21D48B50-0DE5-4A8F-B60C-469F4A82F947}:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft ISATAP
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta tunelowa Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta tunelowa isatap.{79E82DF0-453F-454D-95F9-CFA7A8E45CF7}:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft ISATAP #2
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta tunelowa isatap.{6B6368D1-27FE-4BA4-BC5E-098BD9606D7E}:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft ISATAP #3
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta tunelowa isatap.{2EE7E860-FB70-4B92-B024-B49A26B3631D}:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft ISATAP #4
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta tunelowa isatap.{FC07C609-8B4D-4D04-AB3F-7F97A7EB64BF}:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft ISATAP #6
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak

Karta tunelowa isatap.{590A6368-1017-4AC6-A814-15DEF0A4DF74}:

   Stan nośnika . . . .  . . . . . . .: Nośnik odłączony
   Sufiks DNS konkretnego połączenia :
   Opis. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft ISATAP #7
   Adres fizyczny. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP włączone . . . . . . . . . . : Nie
   Autokonfiguracja włączona . . . . : Tak
```

"Karta komórkowego połączenia szerokopasmowego Komórkowe połączenie szerokopasmowe 4:" - this is the name I can't catch using console `netsh`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the full output from `ipconfig /all`.

Answer (score 1):

After searching and learning this stuff finally found out my network lays in different a group, namely, I can manage these operations by using:

**connect:**

```
netsh mbn connect interface="Huawei Internet" connmode=name name="Orange"
```

**disconnect:**

```
netsh mbn disconnect interface="Huawei Internet"
```

and this works!